# How can you use grep (or some similar program) to read all files as text files?

Tags: grep

I am trying to find a string in a few files, however the files are currently read by Ubuntu as image files. How can I change this (in grep or in Ubuntu itself)?

Comment: Take a look at the "strings" command.  Feed output to grep.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"read by Ubuntu as"*? what is the output of `file yourfilename` on the file(s)? FYI you can instruct grep to treat binary files as text (using the `-a` or `--binary-files=` options), however some bytes in the matched output may mess with your terminal

Comment: `strings -n 8 /usr/bin/grep | grep 'stack overflow'`